# PHP JSON encode issue and retrieval issue

Tags: json

I usually do this to encode simple strings to be obtained via an AJAX request.

```
$str = '<img src="someinage.png" />';
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'OK',$str));
```

The output:

```
{"status":"OK","html":"<img src="someinage.png" />"}
```

See the double quotes, how can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the html_entity_decode function for the `$str`.

```
$str = '<img src="someinage.png" />';
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'OK',html_entity_decode($str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$str = "<img src='someinage.png' />";
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'OK',$str));
```

Comment: this is an example the $str actually holds a huge html data. Not possible to convert every double quotes into single.

Answer (score -1):

> See the double quotes, how can I avoid this issue?

Look at the [second parameter `json_encode` can take](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) – `JSON_HEX_QUOT` or `JSON_HEX_TAG`, or the combination of the two (depending on what context you are trying to mask the data for) should be able to solve your problem (without having to change the format of your data or to even have to manipulate it inside the function call as in Sarah’s answer).