# Create json_encode in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

i just want to create a json encoded data from mysql result using php.I have a table of employee details and i wan to show a table data from these json_encoded array.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ]
]
}
```

I am new to json_encode , I tried like

```
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while($res_sel = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
    $array['data'][$i] = $res_sel['name'];
    $i++;
}

$json_val = json_encode($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_val);
```

Comment: So.. what is your issue? desired result, current result?

Comment: Read [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: No need of `print_r` for JSON, after all it's a JSON **String**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php json encod issue and retrival issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967718/php-json-encod-issue-and-retrival-issue)

Comment: replace mysqli_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: You don't need that `$i` incrementing there. Just use `$array['data'][] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_row()`:

```
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
$array = array();
while($res_sel = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sel)){
    $array['data'][] = $res_sel;
}
```

Otherwise you will not have datasets in separate subarrays, but - as in your example - only `name` values.